# How to import XLSX using POI in Coldfusion

Tags: java, excel, coldfusion, apache-poi, xlsx

I am currently trying to read in an XLSX file with POI in a CFC.

I am using this code:

```
    <cfobject action="create" type="Java" class="XLSImportWorkbook" name="xlsWorkbookObj">  
        <cfset status = xlsWorkbookObj.importWorkbook(JavaCast("string", #local.FilePath#))>
        <cfset xlsWorkbookObj.fetchWorksheet(0)>
```

This actually works fine except for that it will only take XLS files. There is a class called XLSXImportWorkbook so I assumed I could simply change the class to that. That doesn't work however as I get the error.

```
The importWorkbook method was not found.
```

I would have thought the process would be similar but obviously not. If there is no importWorkbook method, how do I go about importing it?

Comment: Did you cfdump your object to see what methods were available?

Comment: Yes, there appear to be many similar function to the XLSimportworkbook but it is missing the import method.

Comment: Did it have any methods that looked promising?  Alternatively, are you on a high enough version of CF to use the spreadsheet tags and/or functions?

Comment: Im pretty sure yeah, using CF10. I have been able to read in XLS files and manipulate them. It is literally just a case of figuring out how to get the XLSX import working.

Comment: `XLSImportWorkbook` sounds like a custom class, *not* one that is part of the standard POI library. (Otherwise, you would need to use the full package path ie `org.apache.poi.*` to instantiate it with cfobject). If you are running CF10, why not just try [`SpreadSheetRead()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-7b585809122c5a12c54-8000.html)?